# How to redirect from http://127.0.0.1:8000 to http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/ while starting the Django development server?

Tags: python, django

When I start Django development server, I am getting **Page Not Found** on **http://127.0.0.1:8000/** as I have configured my login page URL in **http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/**.

But I want to start my Django development server with http://127.0.0.1:8000/login so that I can see the login page directly and i dont need to put /login/ manually.

Can anybody help me with this?

I have used the below code for login page,

```
class LoginIndexView(LoginView):
    
    template_name = 'login.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        
        url = reverse_lazy('list_view')
        return resolve_url(url)
```

The URL pattern, I have used like below,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', LoginIndexView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True), name = 'loginindex',),    
]
```

Comment: Are you trying to host something on `/` that requires authenticated users? Or is there not supposed to be anything there?

Comment: Create any view for `/` and use the `@login_required` decorator on it.

Comment: I have updated with my login code. Please let me know the next update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpResponseRedirect`

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def index(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect("login")
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
]
```

Comment: I have used LoginView and updated the code with the URL pattern. Let me know the next steps.

Comment: what's the next step? didn't you want to be redirected to the login page when the get request to the homepage?